# Login Form Mysqli php with HTML

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I have an HTML login form, and a php code that commences a database connection and enables logging in through simple HTML. What I want to do is to implement the php code on a certain design I have. 
I am having problems connecting that php code with the desired design(the HTML form)

The login html form:

```
<li id="login">
  <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
    Log in <span>▼</span>
  </a>
  <div id="login-content">
    <form>
      <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address" required>   
        <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed in</label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>                     
</li>
<li id="signup">
  <a href="">Sign up FREE</a>
</li>
```

The PHP MySQL code including an HTML login form:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<!-- The HTML login form -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
<?php
} else {
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
        // do stuffs
    }
}
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> try this in else part

```
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    mysqli_select_db($mysqli,DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no ".$mysqli->connect_errno." : ".$mysqli->connect_error."</p>";
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
        // do stuffs
    }
```

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 37

Comment: yo have to write this code inside `else {--this code--}`

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli() on line 19
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0008 245368 {main}( ) ..\2.php:0

Comment: If you want this to do stuff after successfully logging in you get : PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at. How can this be fix with using you code above please?